# Meteor js templates rendered vs onRendered

Tags: user-interface, meteor, version

After working fine with

Template.name.rendered  = function () {
   .....
}

I changed this to:

Template.name.onRendered(function(){
   .....
})

but I don't have the same results and I don't find too much documentation about the differences, some one would help me please? or someone knows where I can see the differences?

Comment: Can you describe a little bit more what kind of different behavior your are experiencing?

Comment: It is like in onRendered the data doesn't arrive as soon as in rendered does, I have to refresh to have the correct data, but maybe I'm using in a wrong way (because the api changed), I would like to see the differences in some place, but I don't find too much documentation about that :(

Comment: There's no difference between `rendered` and `onRendered`, it's supposed to be the exact same API.

Comment: They should be equivalent and produce the same results. Can you post your code inside the rendered function?

Comment: Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function(){   this.autorun( ) {  Template.currentData(); ..............show that data.............  }    })

Comment: rendered is getting deprecated. use `Template.home.onRendered(// function)`

Comment: @zilevav Looking at the implementation [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/blaze/template.js#L203) there's no way there's a difference between those two "uses" unless you're comparing it with the behavior on some older version of Meteor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Meteor 1.0.4 `rendered` got deprecated and replaced by `onRendered`:

> Add onRendered, onCreated, and onDestroyed methods to Template. Assignments to Template.foo.rendered and so forth are deprecated but are still supported for backwards compatibility. 
>   Source: [History.md](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md)

If you see "wrong" behavior when using `onRendered` please make sure you are using Meteor 1.0.4 or newer.

Comment: I am using Meteor 1.2.1 and the onRendered simply does not fire, while rendered does :(

Comment: Hi @PredragStojadinović, I have found the same issue. With onRendered it was simply not working. I am using a sequence of collection.find calls and updating the DOM with jquery. With rendered it was working beautifully. I then found my mistake... I had chnaged to Template.name.onRendered = function () { ..... }  , only changing rendered for onRendered, instead of using it as a callback like Template.name.onRendered(function(){ ..... }) . Not using "=". After correcting it, it started working fine.