# what is the Template.templateName.rendered= function(){} in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is my first Meteor project and I'm trying to understand the Meteor itself at the same time. Now I've came across with the following syntax :

```
Template.editor.rendered = function() {
    // some stuff here 
}
```

Altough I've looked at the web, I could not find what is this kind of function. I mean I wonder what should I put inside this function and when this function will be called ? For example, if I have a url like `localhost:3000/test`, when I type this url into browser, does this action call `Template.test.rendered= function()` ?

Comment: This is very basic, plain Javascript. You declare `Template.editor.rendered` as a function. Nothing more, nothing less. Nothing special about this particular *syntax*.

Comment: rendered is deprecated, use `onRendered(function(){` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rendered` callback is similar to `ready()` in jQuery or `DOMContentLoaded` in Vanilla Javascript.

From [Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered)

> Register a function to be called when an instance of this template is inserted into the DOM.
>
> Callbacks added with this method are called once when an instance of Template.myTemplate is rendered into DOM nodes and put into the document for the first time.

Comment: Are the onrendered and rendered same ? @Tushar

Comment: @zwlayer Yes, they both are same

Comment: @zwlayer See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809702/meteor-js-templates-rendered-vs-onrendered

Comment: @zwlayer Using `rendered` is deprecated. Use `Template.x.onRendered(function () { ... })`