# Meteor is there a Template reRendered event?

Tags: meteor

Is there an event that gets fired when the template changes based on the data change?

I noticed that the `Template.foo.rendered` is fired only once, and I would like to catch the re-render event if possible...

Also, from the [Meteor documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) and also from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29816574/271873), it seams that we should use `onRendered` instead of `rendered` for Meteor 1.0.4 and higher, but I am using Meteor 1.2.1 and the `onRendered` simply does not fire, while `rendered` does just fine :(

Comment: Could you please provide your code? Do you want to have a callback when a reactive data source changes?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once had similar need as you describe, it took some time to figure it out. (I have described the story with rendered and onRendered [here](https://medium.com/@martunta/meteor-js-iron-router-and-materialize-css-8248b121b2d6#.4k2hkaw9t))

In short - `rendered` fires only once, when component is first rendered. Which is fine until, I want to remove and add back some parts of it dynamically. Solution I found was, that my big template had to be split into smaller chunks, each defined as its own template. Then when adding or removing those smaller chunks, reactivity would do its job and rendered would be called on each template, on each dynamic adding or removal.

I hope that this gives you an idea how to work around this issue, as there is no re-rendering event available in Meteor.